# Did anyone has any idea how to configure Jenkins to execute different TestNG test suite for different committed code

Tags: java, tortoisesvn, jenkins-plugins, visualsvn

Did anyone has any idea how to configure Jenkins to **execute different TestNG test suite** for **different committed code**.

ex. If we **commit Database mapping** related classes to SVN subversion then **Jenkins should execute database related test classes only**.

ex. If we **commit web service** related classes to SVN subversion then **Jenkins should execute web service related test classes only**.

**Is there any plugin to achieve this requirement**.

Comment: This is a bad idea. What happens if changes in your database-mapping code break your Web service?

Comment: This both test cases are independent to each other.

Comment: Can we execute package specific test cases according to committed code,    .